# nested routing angular 6 doesn't fire

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Hi everybody I have module with components I want to  add component inside one of them as I have admin and this module has children page and it is routing is

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      { path : 'Dashboard' , component: DashboardComponent},
      // { path: 'User', component: UserComponent },
      { path: 'User', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'},
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'Dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ],
  },
  { path: '**', component: SystemErrorComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

under user, I have added multi-component like add and details and I have routing for it it is

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'userlist', component: UserlistComponent },
      { path : 'adduser' , component: AdduserComponent},
      { path: ':id/Userdetails', component: UserdetailsComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'userlist', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ],
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

I also add  in admin HTML and user HTML 
when I click user link  I got error Error: Component UserComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
 and not open what is the error in my routing?

Answer (score 0):

The error simply states that the UserComponent isn't available for loading.

So first check if the UserComponent is in the **declarations** array of UserModule.

If this doesn't help, then you might need to post the AdminModule and UserModule source.

Answer (score 0):

I have added all component into declarations and remove user declarations of the user from admin then it works